# Parsing an array from HTTP response in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, http, nsarray

The response is something like this

```
Array({"ResultSet":{"Query":"xxxx","Result":[]}})
```

How to parse the string into a NSArray?

Answer (score 2):

it should work with NSJSONSerialization, it converts NSData input to all foundation objects (NSArray, NSDictionary):

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error) {
    //handle error
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
}
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work with array data. I got the following error[ error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x10f73c2b0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}]

Comment: your response might be malformed. did you verify it with a json validation service (e.g. http://jsonlint.com/)?